# Premake5 specify platform at command line?

Tags: premake

I have a list of platforms in my premake5.lua file like this:

```
platforms { "windows", "macos", "ios" }
```

How do specify the platform when invoking premake?

This doesn't work:

```
premake5 xcode4 --platform=macos
```

I just get the error `Error: invalid option 'platform'`

Comment: Maybe they changed it from v4 to v5; perhaps try `--cc=macos` instead.

Comment: Pretty sure 'cc' refers to the C compiler. In any case, it doesn't work.

Comment: It's fairly unclear by the documentation what to do. Maybe you need to define the `--platform` option in your `.lua` file.

Comment: I don't even see any way at all to define a custom token at the command line.

Comment: [I might've found it](https://github.com/premake/premake-core/blob/63a1e5ff3b66ef97392f42a8df7da91fc863ecf4/src/_premake_init.lua#L1710) ... `--os=macosx`, still can't be certain this is what you're looking for though. The documentation is all over the place unfortunately. To create new triggers or options check this page: https://github.com/premake/premake-core/wiki/Command-Line-Arguments, more specifically, https://github.com/premake/premake-core/wiki/newoption.

Comment: Yeah, that works! I wish it wasn't restricted to a predefined list of platforms, but I suppose it will do. This seems to work: `location ("build/" .. os.target())`. Thanks =)

Comment: great! and you're welcome. I'll put that as an answer if you want. let me know...

Comment: Sure, go for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command-line options must have changed somewhat from v4 to v5. [Looking at the source code](https://github.com/premake/premake-core/blob/63a1e5ff3b66ef97392f42a8df7da91fc863ecf4/src/_premake_init.lua#L1710) the option to use would be `--os`, (`--platform` doesn't appear to be there):

```
--os=macosx
```

You can also define new options, which [this document](https://github.com/premake/premake-core/wiki/newoption) explains in more detail.